# Make Top Row of a Page in an UWP App Transparent?

Tags: c#, background, uwp, transparent

I have a UWP app designed to run in Windows 10 phones.  I find that the top row of the page of the app blocks the top row of the screen.  The top row of the screen has Wi-Fi signal strength and battery strength indicators that I don't want the app to block.  Currently I work around this problem by adding something like this in all the pages in my app:

```
if      ( SysInfo.SystemVersion.Equals( "10.0.10586.107" ) )
        {
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.White );
        this.Opacity = 0.90;
        }
else if ( SysInfo.SystemVersion.Equals( "10.0.14393.693" ) )
        {
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Black );
        this.Opacity = 0.99;
        }
else    // All else, choose this "catch-all" settings.
        // And hope for the best.
        {
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Black );
        this.Opacity = 0.99;
        }
```

The SysInfo.SystemVersion is based on the program in this web page:
https://www.suchan.cz/2015/08/uwp-quick-tip-getting-device-os-and-app-info/

My app has white background and black text and black border -- in other words, it is simply black on white.

This "works".  However, I feel that this is just a workaround.  It really looks like a "band-aid".  And I will need to re-fix the "fixed" when a new OS Build comes around and this workaround doesn't work any more.

Would you please help me with these:

- Why is the top-row blocked if I don't use this workaround?
- Why does the workaround work?
- Why does a different version of OS Build require a different background color and opacity to get this workaround to work?
- What is the better solution?

Please let me know.  Thanks.

Jay C

Comment: You want to hide the status bar completely?

Comment: I assume the status bar that you are referring to is the top row of the screen in a Windows 10 phone.  No, I want the opposite.  I want the various indicators in the top row of the screen to remain visible while my app is running in the foreground.  Hope this clarifies what I want to accomplish.